# Diverge test, a function powered by itself

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CXp8.png)

I don't how the hint can be generalized to common functions f(x).

Answer (score 1):

i think we can use that $$e^x\geq x-1$$ for all real $x$
writing $$f(n)^{f(n)}=e^{\log(f(n)\cdot f(n)}\geq (\log(f(n))-1)\cdot (f(n)-1)$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get how to use this inequality...